# Apply coupon to active subscription from stripe customer portal

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

How we can enable user to apply coupon to active subscription from stripe customer portal. I have already enabled "Allow customers to apply promotion codes" flag from stripe portal(Configure your customer portal).

Is there any option available in customer portal where we can suggest users about available coupons, which users can use for their subscription.

Comment: You'd have to share a promotion code with them some other way(like emailing them directly or so on), the portal doesn't have options for suggesting available coupons etc(you could of course also just apply a coupon directly to the subscription in the API if you like)